# Pig Rank function not generating rank in output

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am facing this bizarre issue while using `Apache Pig` **rank** utility. I am executing the following code:

```
email_id_ranked = rank email_id;
store email_id_ranked into '/tmp/';
```

So, basically I am trying to get the following result

```
1,email1
2,email2
3,email3
...
```

Issue is sometime pig dumps the above result but sometimes it dumps only the emails without the rank. Also when I dump the data on screen using `dump` function pig returns both the columns. I don't know where the issue is. Kindly advice.

Please let me know if you need any more information. Thanks in advance.

**Pig version: Apache Pig version 0.11.0-cdh4.6.0**

Comment: do you mean running same script w/o any change in environment outputs emails with and without ranks in different runs?

Comment: @GauravPhapale Your're absolutely correct

Comment: try using RANK by column.
e.g. email_id_ranked = rank email_id by $0;

Comment: @GauravPhapale no luck same result...